# Can't find my mistake in very simple Verilog Module

Tags: signal-processing, verilog, xilinx, system-verilog

The code is essentially the following: Value counts clock cycles to 150 and then resets to 0 and VOutReg counts how many times Value went to 150 and when VOutReg gets to 50 times, it resets to 0. That's it. But when I write a Test Fixture with only the following code: forever #20 clock = not clock all i get in the result is the clock changing and not ValueOut.

Code:

```
module Asd(
input CLK,
output [8:0] ValueOut
);


 reg [9:0] Value;
 reg [8:0] VOutReg;

 initial Value = 0;
 initial VOutReg = 0;

 always@(posedge CLK) begin
    if (Value == 150)
        Value <= 0; 
    else
        Value <= Value + 1;
 end

 always@(posedge CLK) begin
    if (VOutReg == 50)
        VOutReg <= 0;
    else begin
        if (Value == 150)
            VOutReg <= VOutReg + 1;
    end
 end

 assign ValueOut = VOutReg;
endmodule
```

Comment: Do you see Value or VOutReg changing at all in your simulation or are they stuck at zero?  Maybe put a space between your always and the @ sign?

Comment: The solution is to add initial statements for all registers a.k.a.
initial Value = 0;
initial VOutReg = 0;
and thats it. It did not give me any values before

Comment: @user2809337 Ah ok.  Yes you need to initialize counter signals to something either by a reset signal or an initial assignment.  Otherwise they will be unknown forever.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem I see with your code is your last if statement doesn't have an else associated with it, therefore VOutReg is undefined if `Value != 150`.  Also you're creating inferred latches which are undesirable.  To truly create a register, you need a `Next` term `D` for each register which is always defined. Then `Q`, the register output, becomes `D`, the register input, on every positive clock edge. Like so:

```
module Asd(
input CLK,
output [8:0] ValueOut
);


reg [9:0] Value;
reg [8:0] VOutReg;
reg [9:0] ValueNxt;
reg [8:0] VOutRegNxt;

initial Value = 'b0;
initial VOutReg = 'b0;

always@(posedge CLK)
begin
       Value <= ValueNxt; 
       VOutReg <= VOutRegNxt;
end

always@(*)
begin
   if (Value == 150)
   begin
       ValueNxt = 'b0;

       if (VOutReg == 50)
           VOutRegNxt = 'b0;
       else
           VOutRegNxt = VoutReg + 1'b1;
   end
   else
   begin
       ValueNxt = Value + 1'b1;       
       VoutRegNxt = VOutReg;
   end
end

assign ValueOut = VOutReg;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the initial statements using a reset signal (`RST`) as below.

```
module Asd(
input CLK,
input RST,
output [8:0] ValueOut
);


 reg [9:0] Value;
 reg [8:0] VOutReg;

//initial Value = 0;
//initial VOutReg = 0;

 always@(posedge CLK, negedge RST) begin
    if (!RST) begin
      Value <= 0; 
    end
    else begin
      if (Value == 150)
          Value <= 0; 
      else
          Value <= Value + 1;
    end
 end

 always @(*) begin
    if (VOutReg == 50)
        VOutReg <= 0;
    else begin
        if (Value == 150)
            VOutReg <= VOutReg + 1;
    end
 end

 assign ValueOut = VOutReg;
endmodule
```

Also your code uses rising edge of `CLK` as the control signal for the `VoutReg` logic which may not give you the intended value since from your description the `Voutreg` depends only on `Value` not `CLK`. You need to use the `Value` as control signal. You may register this out put using a separate `always` block if you need.